# Which of the following statements are true for all such $a$ and $b$? Prove the statement or give a counterexample.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

For each of the following, decide whether or not the equality holds for all $a,b$.  Prove each of the true statements and provide counterexamples for the false ones.

$$\gcd(a+b,a-b)=\gcd(a,b)$$

$$\gcd(a+b,2a-b)=\gcd(a,b)$$

$$\gcd(a+b,2a+b)=\gcd(a,b)$$

$a$ and $b$ have to be positive integers, where $a>b$.

I said the first statement is not true. Let $a=5$ and $b=3$. $a+b=8$, and $a-b=2$. Their gcd is $2$, but $5$ and $3$ are relativ3ly prime, so their gcd is $1$, which is not correct using the statement.

Statement 2 is also false for $a=7$ and $b=2$. $gcd(9,12)=3$ and $gcd(7,2)=1$, and $3$ doesn't equal $1$

I said the third statement is true because if $a$ divides $b$, then a+b and 2a+b both will sum to something that has the gcd. Is my reasoning flawed?

Comment: Hint:  Always a good idea to work some examples.

Comment: I have, just I'm not sure if I am picking the right numbers. For example, picking numbers that divide each other instead of picking numbers that have the same gcd but dont divide each other.

Comment: It's hard to believe you tried any numbers at all if you think the first claim is true.  What are some of the numbers you tried?

Comment: Oh, I see. It is the problem for picking the right numbers.

Comment: So?  Have you found a counterexample for the first one?

Comment: Yes,editing right now.

Comment: the title says for all such a and b but what conditions are on a and b already ?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: Ok! So you have a valid counterexample for the first one.  Good start.  Now, you think the second one might be false...can you find a counterexample to that one?  Hint:  Really, try some more examples.

Comment: Yes, 7 and 2 i believe.

Comment: Good!   Note:  if you want to practice proofs, you might try to show that the first claim is "almost true".  That is, $\gcd(a+b,a-b)$ is either $\gcd(a,b)$ or $2\times \gcd(a,b)$.  A similar result holds for the second (though it isn't $2$ you sometimes must multiply by).

Comment: For the third:  your intuition is good for that one, but your argument is insufficient.  Basically you are just saying "it's true because it is true" which is not good enough.  You will need to try to write a proper proof.

Comment: Well, the gcd(a,b) must divide a+b and 2a+b

Comment: Yes, that is so (and that also holds for the other two supposed equalities).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66096/discussion-between-gerard-l-and-lulu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notes on a proof of the third one.

It is clear that $\gcd(a,b)$ divides both $a+b,\,2a+b$.  We need to argue that any common divisor of $a+b,\,2a+b$ divides both $a,b$.

We will use the fact that if $d$ divides $m,n$ then $d$ divides $Am+Bn$ for all $A,B\in \mathbb Z$.

So, suppose that $d$ divides both $a+b,\,2a+b$.  Then:

1. $d\,|\,a$  Proof:  $d$ must divide $2a+b-(a+b)=a$
2. $d\,|\,b$  Proof:  $d$ must divide $2(a+b)-(2a+b)=b$

and we are done.